# QML Audio stops 400 milliseconds before the end

Tags: qt, qml

Can someone, please, explain this odd behavior of my application.
I am using Qt 5.1.0 and msvc2010.
This is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0

Window {
   visible: true
   width: 360
   height: 360
   MouseArea {
      anchors.fill: parent
      onClicked: {
         playAudio.play()
      }
   }

    Audio {
        id: playAudio
        source: "zvuky/1.mp3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're on Windows, try playing the same file in Windows Media Player. Does it get cut off there too?

Comment: No, in Windows Media Player, there is no cut off. There an audio is played well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finelly I found solution. 
Everything works perfect with Audio element when I used Qt 5.2.1(msvc2012)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have any error. Maybe it's due to the `mp3` file and Qt is not able to load it.

Did you try to convert the `mp3` file to `wav`? Sometimes it's better to use `SoundEffect` instead of `Audio`.

You could also try the `MediaPlayer` type.

Here you have an example. It's in [GitHub](https://github.com/ftena/qt-snippets/tree/master/qml-audio) where you can download the audio clips.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

        onClicked: {
            if (mouse.button == Qt.RightButton)
                playMP3.play()
            else
                playWAV.play()
        }
    }

    SoundEffect {
        id: playWAV
        source: "res/kid_giggle.wav"

        onPlayingChanged: {
            console.log("SoundEffect - onPlayingChanged - category: " + category)
        }
    }

    MediaPlayer {
        id: playMP3
        source: "res/kid_giggle.mp3"

        onPlaying: {
            console.log("MediaPlayer - onPlaying - duration: " + duration)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SoundEffect works well but just for wav files. My application has many audio file and it would make it too big size. Is there a way to play mp3 in SoundEffect element?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `SoundEffect` cannot play compressed audio files. What about `MediaPlayer`? Did it work? BTW, none of your mp3 files are played when you use the `Audio` component?

Comment: MadiaPlayer also cuts off end of audio.
With Audio component any mp3 file is played, but always there is a cut off at the end.
BTW I don't have such problem with Qt Quic UI project. Problem is only with Qt Quick Application project.

Comment: I've just seen your answer. Cool! ;) Happy coding!